# Подскажите про формирование строк NSString а AlertView

Tags: xcode, objective-c

раньше я формировал строки таким для AlertView

```
NSString *alertForGuessWin1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You guess number %d ",i_2];
NSString *alertForGuessWin2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"for: %d step" , count_step];
NSString *alertForGuessWin3 = [alertForGuessWin1 stringByAppendingString:alertForGuessWin2];

UIAlertView *alertGuessWin =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation"
                                                     message:alertForGuessWin3
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"New Game" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertGuessWin show];
```

Возникли вопросы, как формировать строку прям в message (c использыванием переменных и текста) чтоб в одну строку уложиться.

И Самое главное, как сделать перенос строки ( в c++ было чтото типа /n )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утро вечера мудренее:

```
UIAlertView *alertGuessWin =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation"                                                    message:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You guess number %d \n for: %d step",i_2,count_step]
                                                         delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"New Game" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertGuessWin show];
```